# horizontal alignment to the right + wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, alignment

i have a window wpf application, presenting a list of items. 
i would like the list to be presented to the right, and not to the left as it is at the moment.
my partly xaml file is attached. 
i tried attaching the attribute horizontalalignment to the textblocks and the images, but nothing changed.

```
   <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cl:FolderData}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <Border BorderThickness="1">
        <!-- Drop="FolderStackPanel_PreviewDrop" -->
        <StackPanel DragEnter="StackPanel_PreviewDragEnter" DragLeave="StackPanel_PreviewDragLeave" 
                         Name="FolderStackPanel" Drop="FolderStackPanel_PreviewDrop" Orientation="Horizontal" ContextMenu="{StaticResource cmExportDelete}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Image Name="NodeIcon" Width="24"  Margin="5" Height="24" Source="pack://application:,,,/ExportToolWpf;component/Images/folder_icon.png"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,5,0,0" >
                <TextBlock Name="NodeHeader" FontSize="11" Text="{Binding Path=FolderName}" />
                <StackPanel Name="IdPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="10" Foreground="Gray" Text="Client ID:" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="10" Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding Path=ClientId}" Margin="0,0,7,0" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="10" Foreground="Gray" Text="Project ID:"/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="10" Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding Path=ProjectId}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border> </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

i apriciate any help you can offer. 
thanks, hadas.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

You can introduce a grid just above the stackpanel and use Column # 1 for obtaining right alignment

Answer (score 0):

Use `DockPanel` instead of `StackPanel` and try to set `HorizontalContentAlignment`